# how write unit test for styles custom component of react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Can we write a unit test for styles using enzyme, jest?

```
wrapper.prop('style')
```

is undefined for me;
can we check some css prop? like: display or color etc.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can use `chai-enzyme` which provides testing [styles](https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme#stylekey-val).

2.) You can use the [get](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/get.html) method of enzyme and then test it like:

```
const wrapperStyle = wrapper.get(0).style;
expect(wrapperStyle).to.have.property('opacity', '1');
```

Comment: I use jss for styles;
Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

Comment: Can you provide the part of the code where you mounting the wrapper?

Comment: renderWithIntl(<SomeComponent {...props} />)
i find resolution (use renderWithIntl) and use jquery
maybe yoy know how i can emulate print mode? (for testing styles in @media print)